# Laravel Input::hasFile returning false while Input::file() gives all the information about file

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4, cpanel, web-hosting

I have written following basic file upload code which **works perfectly on localhost**. On live version, `Input::hasFile('profile_picture')` returns false consequently **file is not moved to the required directory**, while `$filename = Input::file('profile_picture')->getClientOriginalName();` works fine and receives the file name.

On removing the if hasFile check before moving the file, **the move function throws exception** saying,
`Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileException`
`File could not be uploaded: missing temporary directory.`

What I have confirmed:

- Large file size is not the problem, I have tried to upload 1.4kb file as well as I have `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` in my `index.php`.
- Html form has no common problem like missing `'files' => true`, and csrf token.

upload.blade.php contains:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'api/users', 'files' => true]) }}
File: {{ Form::file('profile_picture') }}
{{ Form::hidden('email', 'asimawan.62@gmail.com') }}
{{ Form::submit('send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Generated form looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/api/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="96OKRdiwnHlku0uMLYYpHPjAIKAiqoKRp372fUWc">
File: <input name="profile_picture" type="file">
<input name="email" type="hidden" value="asimawan.62@gmail.com">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

routes.php contains:

```
Route::get('upload', function() {
    return View::make('upload');
});

Route::resource('api/users', 'UsersController');
```

UsersController::store()

```
    public function store()
    {
        if ($this->user->isValid($data = Input::all())) {

            $data = Input::all();
            $filename = Input::file('profile_picture')->getClientOriginalName();
            $data['profile_picture'] = $filename;

            if (Input::hasFile('profile_picture')) {
                Input::file('profile_picture')->move(public_path('pictures/profile'), $filename);
            } else {
                return "Input::hasFile('profile_picture') has returned false. Size = "
                    . Input::file('profile_picture')->getClientSize();
            }

            $this->user->fill($data);
            $this->user->save();
            return Response::json($this->user);
        }

        return Response::json($this->user->errors);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look's like a permission's problem on the server.

try this php function to know what is the path for the temporary files

```
ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
```

Then, check the permissions of the folder.

Comment: spot on! It returns nothing.

Comment: I've added `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', '/tmp');` in my `index.php` but still `ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');` returns nothing.

Comment: i would actually like to know the solution to this too